# Azure Jenkins Android SDK not found

Tags: android, azure, jenkins

I´ve created a fresh jenkins server in azure, everything works fine so far, but the build cannot find the ANDROID_HOME enviroment variable even if it is set.

[image: ANDROID_HOME EnvVar]

[image: Console output]

[image: Azure AndroidSDK]

I´m really not sure whats going on here, because it seems to be that everything is set up correctly. Is it possible that jenkins is using a different user so the variable is not found?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this issue is not related to Azure. Looks like its related to permission issue.

Try to resolve the issue by following below steps.

1. Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System
2. Check for "Environment variables"
3. Add name: ANDROID_HOME and value:
4. click "add"
5. Scroll down and click “save”

If you have already done with the above steps, then try to make sure you have given 777 permission to android sdk dir as shown below (in some cases better to provide permission to its parent directory).

*chmod 777 your_android_sdk_dir*

If you have already done with the above step, then try to restart Android Studio and see if it builds the project successfully.

Hope this helps!!